# Escape % in MySQL queries with match

Tags: mysql, escaping

I'm using the following SQL query for a search engine:

```
$sql =    'SELECT *, MATCH(query) AGAINST(\''.$keywords.'\' ) AS relevance
          FROM `queries` 
          WHERE MATCH(query) AGAINST(\''.$keywords.'\' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
          ORDER BY relevance DESC, length(query) ASC, query ASC';
```

When the user enters the character `%`, the query didn't match. I would like to get the row containing the % character.

I already try to escape the % character with the following: `\%`, `[%]` and `!%`, but none is working properly. It retreived zero row from database.

Comment: *I would like to get the row containing the % character.* ONLY this character? Show example(s) of literals to be searched for ($keywords value) without escaping.

Comment: No, of course, otherwise I would not use match! $keyword is a string created with `$keywords = implode("* ", explode(' ',$keywords)).'*';` so if the `%` is in the row, I would like the row to be returned by the query.

Comment: I have asked for an example of VALUE, I am not interested in any CODE.

Comment: For example, if the query is `%`, I expect to match with `%`, `test %` `a %` ... Does it answer to your question ? Nice mustache by the way!

Comment: *Does it answer to your question ?* Not in a form I have asked, but it helps nevertheless. In all cases the percent sign is a separate token which is ignored due to minimal token length setting.

Comment: Arrg, got it. What can I do to avoid this?

Comment: (from th User Manual) *By default, words less than 3 characters in length or greater than 84 characters in length do not appear in an InnoDB full-text search index. Maximum and minimum word length values are configurable using the innodb_ft_max_token_size and innodb_ft_min_token_size variables.* Study all [server variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-parameters.html) like `'innodb_ft_%'`.

Comment: Perfect, thank you for your help.